# Dropdown value gets null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dropdown

I use breakpoint debug it my ClientsId always come null and display on my payments index always is the first value of my Dropdownlist

Model:

```
public class Payments
{
    [Key]
    public int PaymentsId { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PaymentsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a client")]
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public int SelectedClient { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Client { get; set; }
}
```

GET CONTROLLER:

```
  public ActionResult Create(Payments model)
  {
      var liste= new PaymentsViewModel
      {
          Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientList, "ClientId", "ClientName")
      };
      return View(liste);
  }
```

POST CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "....")] PaymentsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.PaymentsCreate();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Payments");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

CREATE VIEW:

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedClient, Model.Clients, "-Please select-", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

--------------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------------

EDIT CONTROLLER (GET):

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id, PaymentsViewModel model)
 {
      if (id == null)
      {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      }
      Payments payments = db.PaymentsList.Find(id);
      if (payments == null)
      {
          return HttpNotFound();
      }
      return View();
  }
```

EDIT CONTROLLER (POST)

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PaymentsId,Paymentnumber,PaymentDate,Amount,Discount,Reference,Total")] Payments payments)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Entry(payments).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(payments);
 }
```

Comment: Where you assign selected clientId from PaymentsViewModel to new Payment object that you save?

Comment: @Ivan How can I set it, if I have it only in my `clientId` only in my entitie not in mt viewmodel?

Comment: You have a SelectedClient property at PaymentsViewModel. At Create method (whick calls on post) you receive selected value. If model is valid in your model must be needed value at SelectedClient property. And at PaymentsCreate you set it to Payments object

Comment: @Ivan I try to put in my Create method (post) like this SelectedClient = model.Clients but obviously it don't found SelectedClient because it's not in my PaymentModel, how can I render it?

Comment: At PaymentsCreate at new Payment object initializer add one more property initialization: 'ClientsId = model.SelectedClient'. An identifer of selected client stores at SelectedClient property of PaymentsViewModel. You set it at '@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedClient....'

Comment: @Ivan I still getting null value, and get always first value of my dropdown, I update my question with change

Comment: You have to add 'SelectedClient' to properties enumerations at Bind(Include... attribute

Comment: You´re totally right, It works now, thankyou so much for your help

Comment: I've made an answer. Could you mark it?

Comment: @Ivan, when I edit my value, it changes my ClientName to my first value again, why it happens? I upload my edit controller

Comment: First, I suppose you need at method Edit(get) set some model to view: return View(model) or return View(payments). It will set current values in view. User edit, not create. Second, I think your problem at Bind(Include... attribute at Edit(post) method. You have not add a 'ClientId' property

Comment: @Ivan  set my ClientId, but says my that Client value(virtual of my payment model) it comes null, and my ClientId gets always value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a ClientsId initialization from model.SelectedClient at PaymentsCreate functions like: ClientsId = model.SelectedClient. And then you need to add SelectedClient string to properties enumeration at Create (post) method to Bind(Include.... attribute